# Dynamically create autoload command from filenames in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, automated-tests, autoload

I am testing a web application with ruby, rspec, capybara and selenium and i ran into an `uninitialized constant ActiveAdminLoginPage` Exception that i don't know how to solve.

In spec_helper.rb i am requiring the following:

```
Dir[File.join(Dir.pwd, 'spec/page_objects/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

I have 2 classes

```
spec/page_objects/products/active_admin_login_page.rb  

module Products
  class ActiveAdminLoginPage < ::ActiveAdminLoginPage
  ...
  end
end
```

inherits from

```
spec/page_objects/active_admin_login_page.rb
```

unfortunately the sub class is loaded before the parent class.

How do i create a autoload command dynamically from all filenames in a directory? 
I would like to replace this command:

`Dir[File.join(Dir.pwd, 'spec/page_objects/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }`

with a autoload command.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect from the autoload? That it will automaticaly load file based on missing constant? You will most likely need to write a "wrapper" anyway as this functionality is not build in. The question is how do you expect it to behave. Typicaly you load all the dependencies through `require(_relative)` for each file. To do the work automaticaly you would need relativly strict naming convention to calculate files to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you use `require` to load your dependency in the file that needs it?

`require` loads a file only once, so you shouldn't encounter any side effects.

Or, even better, you can use `auto_load`, which uses `require` under the hood, but it does it in a smarter way

```
autoload :ActiveAdminLoginPage, 'active_admin_login_page'
```

Comment: i know that this would work but i prefer auto loading files over adding requires manually. If i dont find a solution for autoloading then i go for this approach but before i want to try to get files autoloaded.

Comment: do you know how to create the symbol :ActiveAdminLoginPage from 'active_admin_login_page'? Since im reading all files from the page_object directory i need to do this dynamically.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. Check out http://lifeonubuntu.com/use-rubys-autoload-instead-of-require-for-your-ruby-and-rails-apps/

Comment: i dont want to autoload one single file but rather a complete folder wit subfolders. I would like to replace this line `Dir[File.join(Dir.pwd, 'spec/page_objects/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }` with a autoload command.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without giving Ruby a way to know which file depends on which.